# Laravel is unable to read formdata

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I am making a web app, using angular on the frontend and laravel on the backend. 
But I am getting some issues when I am trying to upload some data to the laravel API.

I am using on Angular the formdata, because I need it for upload files. But when I send the data to Laravel, it does not pass the validation, because Laravel is getting empty data.

This is the function that is called on submit.

```
  onUpload() {
    const fd = new FormData;
    fd.append('video', this.video);
    fd.append('image', this.image);
    fd.append('title', 'Hello world');
    fd.append('description', 'Hello world');
    fd.append('userId', '1');
    fd.append('categoryId', '1');

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    this.http.post('here goes the real url', fd, {
      headers: headers
    }).subscribe(event => {
        console.log(event);
    });
  }
```

And this is my validator on Laravel.

```
    public function rules(){
        $datos = $this->validationData();
        return [
            "description" => ["max:2000"],
            "video" => ["required", "mimes:mp4,mov,ogg"],
            "image" => ["required", "image", "mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,webp"],
            "title" => ["required","min:4", "max:100"],
            "userId" => ["required", "numeric"],
            "categoryId" =>["numeric"]
        ];
    }
```

And also, this is the error message:

```
errors:
image: ["The image field is required."]
title: ["The title field is required."]
video: ["The video field is required."]
userId: ["The user id field is required."]
__proto__: Object
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

I need something extra on Laravel to read the data? Or I am uploading wrong?
Thanks you a lot for your time.

Comment: `this.image` is an image object or URL?

Comment: Is an image object, sorry for the bad name I have put it.

Comment: okay NP, try changing Content-type to `multipart/form-data`

Comment: I am getting the same issue. I have also try to remove temporaly the validator and return all the data from the request and It's returning an empty array.

Comment: Try to change const fd = new FormData; to let  fd = new FormData;. Maybe that is problem because `const` doesnt allow modification. @Francisco

Comment: It's still having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

try changing `Content-type` to `multipart/form-data`

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
});
```

Comment: I have changed it, but the same issue appear. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: could you return $request->all() to check file data on server side.

Comment: I have disabled the validator and put the 'return $request->all()' and I get an empty array.

Comment: you are directly calling rules() function or calling from some other function

Comment: This is from a custom Request. In the controller I have put it on the parameter like a ussual request. I guess that the rules fuction it is auto called when I inject it on the controller function. I hope it clarify you something.

Comment: Some things to try: 1) Check you developer tools. Does angular actually send an empty request or perhaps the data is mangled? 2) What format does your laravel API expect, is it a REST API that expects JSON data, or a normal form submit?

Comment: Laravel is expecting a normal form submit. And in Angular when I get the data from the formdata object I am getting it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete 'Content-Type': '...' from headers. works for me:

my code was: importFile(unit_id, data): Observable { let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data').set('x-access-token', this.token); return this.http.post(this.api + `/unit/${unit_id}/import`, data, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events', headers:headers}).pipe(); }

and now: importFile(unit_id, data): Observable { let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('x-access-token', this.token); return this.http.post(this.api + `/unit/${unit_id}/import`, data, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events', headers:headers}).pipe(); }

Comment: Bro, this solved for me the I am start getting response value and values have been read on server side!